# How to unzip .gz file from blob storage in Azure Data Factory?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have folder (say folder A) in blob storage that has more than one zipped file (.gz format). I want to unzip all the file and save back to folder (say folder B in blob storage).

This is the approach I was trying. GetMetadata-->ForEach Loop.
Inside foreach loop, I tried copy activity. However, the unzipped file is corrupted.
[image]

Comment: Just trying to unzip the file stored in blob storage. It works but the result (unzipped file) is corrupted, means not able to open unzipped file.

Comment: @DineshMadhup Can we see the internal active settings? And the whole error message? Did you set the compression type?

Comment: Actually the issue was file extension. I added file extension and it works for me now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Glad to hear the issue is resolved now：

- "Actually the issue was file extension. I added file extension and it
  works for me now. "

I help you post it and others can know that. This can be beneficial to other community members.